# Добавить ActionBar со стрелкой "назад" к PreferenceActivity

Tags: android

Хочу добавить ActionBar со стрелкой "назад" к PreferenceActivity. Я нашел несколько примеров, но все они слишком сложные. Я могу их использовать, конечно, неужели для такой простой вещи все действительно так сложно или есть простой способ? Например, к простой Activity ActionBar можно добавить одной строчкой кода.

Answer (score 5):

Вот такое решение пробовали?

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Только еще надо добавить к вашему actionBar

```
setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Для начала в манифест добавить.

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="by.avest.manager.activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

В SettingsActivity прописать

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_app);
}

private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (null != actionBar) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```